# How to enable msg and debug logging with Log::Message::Simple

Tags: perl, logging

I'm using Log::Message::Simple and error()s appear immediately.  However, calls to debug() and msg() do nothing -- I have to call `Log::Message::Simple->stack_as_string()` to get these.  How can I get this logging to appear immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, but I've fixed this by specifying the optional 'verbose' parameter to msg() and debug(), for example

```
msg("my message", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the stack_as_string, I thought you had to enable the flag.

```
Log::Message::Simple->stack_as_string(1);
```

HTH